# Approximate Solution to Backwards Recurrence of Dynamic Game

Tags: probability, combinatorics, approximation, game-theory, recursion

Suppose we keep tossing a fair dice until we reach some cumulative sum greater than or equal to $N$. Then, let $S_k$ be the expected value of the final sum, given that the current sum is $k$. We have that $S_{N+j}=N+j$ for $0 \leq j \leq 5$. For $k<N$, we also have the recurrence
\begin{equation*}
S_k=\frac{1}{6} \sum_{j=1}^6 S_{k+j}. 
\end{equation*}
This problem falls into the broader class of problems with a recurrence that has a finite but high base case. At this point, it is possible to write a program to compute $S_0$, the expected sum of the game, but I was wondering if there was any theory that gives good approximations/bounds for such recursions. The steady-state solution is $0$, and a characteristic polynomial approach is ugly.

Comment: The expected value of a fair dice is 3.5... If you continue throwing it the expected sum will be just $n\times 3.5$, the only that can change is the deviation or the coefficient of variation. And any distribution of sums throwing dice can be approximated using a normal distribution.